# simple_form - set default text for "select" element

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, select, rubygems, simple-form

I am using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem in order to create my forms. In one case, I am using "collection" method in order to build a select input element.

What I want, is to set a default text of this "drop down" as a selected option, but the option should not be selected.

For example, if I have a languages list, I want to have a selected options with text "Select language". It's should not be selected as well, in order for validates:presence of the field to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

:prompt option is responsible for that.

```
= simple_form_for :user do |f|
  = f.input :lang, collection: ["Ru", "En"], prompt: "Select language"
```